# file_exist not working WHEN PLACED inside php function

Tags: php

I have searched for **almost similar questions** but none of those gave me the right answer. I have a fully *working* file_exist code in if else statement here. but when i placed it inside a function it doesn't work anymore. Here's the code:

```
if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt")) {  

            $myFile = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
            $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
            fclose($fh);

            echo $theData;

         echo "The file exists." ;                      
    }

    else {
        echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }
```

When I place it inside a function which isn't working:

```
function readexisting(){
    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt")) {  

        $myFile = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Alchemy/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
        fclose($fh);

        echo $theData;

         echo "The file exists." ;                      
    }

    else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
    }

}
```

Also, I want to call the function in image click event. here's the code if it would help:

```
<div class="Thumb popup_element shadow clearfix" id="u2413"><!-- group -->
    <img class="grpelem" id="u2471" alt="This Week's Events" src="images/blank.gif" onclick="readexisting()"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
   </div>
```

I hope you could help me with this. thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to call php function in js event? Good luck

Comment: Hi Alma, no there is no js event here.  Can I use js event? would that be a better way? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`onclick=`](http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)  is used to call javascript function or to run javascript code you can not call a php function using [`onclick=""`](http://w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp), but as you are saying you are getting desired output without function is just because when you clicked on image it just render the same page having your first code and when you moved this code to a function, and as functions does not run by its own you need to call them thats why in second case you did not get expected output.

If you want to call php function using javascript use AJAX

**Calling a PHP function using javascript**

Create a test folder ex. ajax (yourhost/ajax/)

**view.php** (yourhost/ajax/view.php)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple AJAX Example</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Thumb popup_element shadow clearfix" id="u2413"><!-- group -->
          <img class="grpelem" id="u2471" alt="This Week's Events" src="images/blank.gif" onclick="readexisting()"/><!-- state-based BG images -->
        </div>

        <script>
            function readexisting() {
                 jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'controller.php',
                    data: {action: 'readexisting', arguments: 'your data'}, 
                    success:function(data) {
                                         data = data.split("~:~");
                                         alert(data[0]); // message
                                         alert(data[1]); // content
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
    include_once("model.php");

    $obj = new Model();

    switch($_POST["action"]){ 
        case 'readexisting': 
            $obj->readexisting();
        break;      
    } 
?>
```

**model.php**

```
<?php
class Model {

   public function readexisting() {
       if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt")) {  
            $myFile = ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt");
            $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
            $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
            fclose($fh);

            echo "The file exists. ~:~".$theData ;                      
       } else {
            echo "The file $filename does not exist";
       }
   }

}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for explaianing. now i'm clear about the problem. can you suggest a way or code so i can place a js event/function in the "onclick =" wherein the js function calls the working code? shoudl I place the working code in a php function? thanks a lot! I appreciate your answer :)

Comment: can i call php function by using js function alone? i have'nt tried using AJAX yet. thanks

Comment: please check the updates answer I will update it more it does not help you.

Comment: thanks Subodh. i will try and test your code now. i'll let you know about the result shortly thanks again

Comment: Hi again, i tried it but nothing happens when i click the image. hope you can still help me with this. thanks

Comment: if you're still there i hope you can still help me. thanks again :)

Comment: yey! It works!! an alert is popping but it's says that 'The file doesn't exist'. uhm, it's not returning the $filename. can you help me again? and if it's not too much to ask, how can i display the value of the .txt file in a modal pop up? thanks you so much! i really appreciate your answer and your effort for helping me. Thanks!

Comment: one last question please regarding the not returning the $filename..and should i raise another question regarding the displaying of the value of .txt file in a modal pop up? :)

Comment: anyway, i'll mark your answer as correct now. It's not just correct, IT'S GREAT! Thank you so much for the effort! Much Appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2):

With `onclick=` you assign a JavaScript event handler, not a PHP function.

I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but perhaps you can execute the function when something is POSTed to your file.

Comment: if i create a JS function like function callPHP() how can this call the other php function? please show me some codes. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a PHP function the same way as a JavaScript function. This just doesn't work.

```
onclick="readexisting()"
```

You can only call JavaScript functions like this.

Comment: can you show me how to create a JS function that would call the php function? and how can i place the working code inside the php function to be called? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the PHP function from HTML/JS. PHP already finished it's work on server side when HTML/JS start working on the client side.

About file_exists - it doesn't change it's behavior in- or outside of function. So the problem should be in fil path. MAy be it's bacause you have 
    /Project/events/folder-01/event-01.txt
in the 1st case and
    /Alchemy/events/folder-01/event-01.txt
in the 2nd? (Alchemy != Project)

Comment: Hi I changed the path so it would be the same. How can i place the working code in a php function? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call a PHP-Function with onclick (directly) without reloading/loading the page.

But you can use `<a>` tag for alternative solution and call that PHP function.

Comment: @Kaye, that would depend on your situation. If you don't want to load/reload your page then the best suggestion for you is to use `jquery and ajax` if not then you can give you a sample

Comment: can you give me a sample? plaese feel free to edit my code. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you can't call the PHP function From HTML tag like Javascript Function.
you have to change your function to javascript function  to invoke it like this

```
onclick="readexisting()"
```