# How to create notification Message after Saving Record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create Notification Message like "`RECORD SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED`" After Updating or Inserting Record In mydql table.

I have Code as below

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
   if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fin_year SET year = ?, remark=? WHERE ent_no=?"))
   {
      $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $year, $remark, $ent_no);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
  }

 // show an error message if the query has an error
  else
  {
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
  }
}
```

have You any Idea For Notification Message..

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery or AJAX?

Comment: If you are trying to do this using AJAX this simple example may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19089803/1868660

Comment: @Lance: please check link of Subodh Ghulaxe to use Ajex with html

Comment: If this question is about `ajax` then mention it, tag it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u don't want to use AJAX , just check if the query is successfully done and put notification message into temporary parameter and pass it back to view

```
 $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $year, $remark, $ent_no);
      $stmt->execute();
$success=  $mysqli->affected_rows; 
if($success>0){
   echo "success";//or something like this
}else
  {
    echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
  }

      $stmt->close();
```

Comment: Where `ajax` come from, there is no `ajax` tag in the question or am I missing anything ?

Comment: yes, there is no AJAX, but we all just recomend @Sameer to do that with AJAX, cause it would be better, in this case

Comment: what OP means? do i say something to you ?

Comment: `OP` means `originator poster`, who asked the `Question` and `@sameer` was not there when you made the comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the PHP that you've written above is being called on via Query's AJAX function, then you're going to need to generate that message via jQuery too. There's a success callback that's applicable to the AJAX function

```
$.ajax({  
    type:'GET',  
    url:'file.php',  
    data:'',
    success: function() {
        alert('RECORD SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED');
    }
});
```

On a similar note, it's better to use POST than GET when submitting forms.

Comment: There is no `ajax` tag! Am i missing anything ?

Comment: Ohhhh. He must have gotten rid of it. When he first posted it, there was an AJAX tag as well as a jQuery one too

Comment: This is confusing, either delete the answer or mention it here, otherwise you know what could happen in future. Your answer seems irrelevant without the ajax `tag`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (Notification with JS - Alert).

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
       if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fin_year SET year = ?, remark=? WHERE ent_no=?"))
       {
          $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $year, $remark, $ent_no);
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->close();
      }
    ?>
     // show an error message if the query has an error

    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <?php


          else
          {
            echo "<script>alert('ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.')</script>";
          }// if 2
        }// if 1
        ?>

    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

if you want you can use your own POP-UP like Fancy to show the notification.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, try this

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE fin_year SET year = ?, remark=? WHERE ent_no=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $year, $remark, $ent_no);
if($stmt->execute()) { // returns a boolean true on success, false on failure
    echo 'RECORD SUCCESSFULLY INSERTED';
}
else {
    echo 'ERROR OCCURRED!';
}
$stmt->close();
```