# get jquery post value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page say, a.php. In the page, on button click I have invoked the function "sample".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sample(id,no) {     
  jQuery.post('s.php', {  ID: id, Number: no }, function(response) { 
    window.self.location='s.php'            
  });
}
</script>         
<input name="" value="submit" type="button" onClick="return sample('5','10');">
```

I need to get the values posted to s.php.

Is it possible with my above code?

Comment: Check this simple example http://stackoverflow.com/a/19089803/1868660

Comment: `$id = $_POST["ID"]; $number = $_POST["Number"];`

Comment: @letiagoalves i have tried that code. but it shows "Undefined index: gateID"

Comment: gateID doesn't exist!

Comment: @Ammu — Since that code doesn't mention a gateID, there is no way that it would be the cause of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
a.php

<form method="_POST" action="s.php">

<input name="id" value="5">
<input name="number" value="10">
<input name="" value="submit" type="button">

</form>

s.php

<?php
if(isset(id) && isset(number)) {
echo id = $_POST['id'];
echo number = $_POST['number'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the $_POST array: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

The array key will be the same as the form input name, so ID and Number.

```
$id = $_POST['ID'];
$number = $_POST['Number'];
```

Then use the variables as you need. Be careful for SQL injections at this point (clean the input).